# Bounding the modulus of $|e^z - e^w|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that $|e^z - e^w| \leq |z - w|$, where $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$ and Re(z) $\leq 0$, Re(w) $\leq 0$. I'm not sure how to approach this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can fix, say $w$ and consider the function $f(z)=\frac{e^{z}-e^{w}}{z-w}$, for $z\neq w$ and $f(w)=e^{w}$. This function is analytic. To show that its absolute value is $\leq1$ for $Re(z)\leq0$ we only need to show it at the boundary. So, for $Re(z)=0$ and for $Re(z)\to-\infty$.

Comment: @Peyton I'm not sure if you are right. It seems you are trying to use maximum modulus principle, but this is an unbounded region.

Comment: @mathworker21 That doesn't stop the validity of the maximum modulus principle. And that is the reason why $Re(z)\to-\infty$ has to be studied. The domain $Re(z)\leq0$ is just a disc after inversion.

Comment: @Peyton I think it does. In any event, what about $Re(z) = -1$, for example, and $Im(z)$ very large.

Comment: You can use the mean value theorem of the function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$by  $f(t) = e^{tz + (1-t)w}$. In which case this implies that there is $u \in [0,1]$ such that $|f'(u)| \ge |f(1) - f(0)|$. Since $f'(u) = (z-w)e^{uz + (1-u)w}$  we have the result.

Comment: @mathworker21 I already proved to you. Do inversion. The domain becomes a disc. Apply maximum modulus on the disc. Notice the inversion is only a transformation on the domain. The values that the function returns don't change. About that limit, that is a tangential limit to $\infty$ as opposed to a radial limit. You can see that it is tangential in the disc. It is enough to look at the radial limits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma$ be the line segment connecting $z$ to $w$

Now

$$|e^z - e^w| = \left|\int_{\gamma} e^\nu d\nu\right| \le \int_{\gamma} \left|e^\nu\right| |d\nu| \le |z - w|$$

as $Re(z) \le 0$ and $Re(w) \le 0$ and so $|e^\nu| \le 1$

Comment: Hope this is right. Bit rusty with complex analysis.